# Log all Rack middleware invocations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

For benchmarking purposes, I'd like to log all requests and responses handled by any Rack Middleware, in a Rails app. Something like:

```
[Sep 6 09:00:00] Middleware A begins
[Sep 6 09:00:01] Middleware B begins
[Sep 6 09:00:05] Middleware B ends
[Sep 6 09:00:06] Middleware A ends
```

It may be possible by monkey-patching `Rack::Server.call` method, but asking first in case there's a library or option I'm not aware of.